# PHP return value formatting

Tags: php, css, woocommerce, colors, formatting

Could you please help me out how i would be able to customize the output of the below code which was added to wordpress/woocommerce?

Currently it shows the sales price and the regular price, and i'd like to add some customization for each of them, like: coloring (sales price=red); text-decoration (sales price=line-through)..

```
function sr_change_variable_price($price, $product) {
    if ( $product->is_type( 'variable' ) && !is_product() ) 
    {
     return $product->get_variation_regular_price( 'min' ).' '.$product->get_variation_sale_price( 'min' ).' Ft'; // if variable product and non-product page
    } else if ( $product->is_type( 'variable' ) && is_product() )
    {
        return '';  // if variable product and product page
    } else
    {
        return $price;  // other cases
    }
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_price_html', 'sr_change_variable_price', 10, 2 );
```

Thank you very much in advance for any help,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in your function you concating two strings in first condition, in second condition returned an empty string and in else statement returned that self price without change. so as your return type is string there is no problem for merging your prices with another strings such as html tags. if this process don't make problem for another processes of your wordpress, you can use html tags by concating them in your returns:

```
function sr_change_variable_price($price, $product){
    $html_tag = '<span style={some styles}>%s</span>';
    if($product->is_type('variable') AND !is_product()){
        $min = $product->get_variation_regular_price('min') . ' ' . $product->get_variation_sale_price('min');
        $min = $min ' Ft';
        return(sprintf($html_tag, $min));
    }elseif($product->is_type('variable') AND is_product()){
        return('');
    }else{
        return(sprintf($html_tag, $price));
    }
}
add_filter('woocommerce_get_price_html', 'sr_change_variable_price', 10, 2);
```

Comment: Thank you very much, unfortunately the code above was not working as i expected, but based on the logic i was able to edit and i understood the logic! So thank you really!

Comment: welcome to StackOverflow and your welcome. we're here to helping each other. good luck. and if you can please vote up my post i need its reputation

Comment: Sure I voted up, but currently, it won't be visible for others yet:
"Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score."